# Strip trailing zeroes and decimal point

Tags: lua, string-formatting

With Lua, I'm formatting numbers to a variable number of digits and strip trailing zeroes/decimal points like

```
string.format(" %."..precision.."f", value):
  gsub("(%..-)0*$", "%1"):
  gsub("%.$", "")
```

Value is of type number (positive, negative, integer, fractional).

So the task is solved, but for aesthetic, educational and performance reasons I'm interested in learning whether there's a more elegant approach - possibly one that only uses one `gsub()`.

`%g` in `string.format()` is no option as scientific notation is to be avoided.

Comment: Are there some constraints applicable on `value`?

Comment: Well, it's a number of some kind, positive or negative, integer or fractional.

Comment: I'd change line 2 to `:gsub("(%.%d-)0+$", "%1")`. It skips the substitution if there are no zeroes, and restricts the characters after the dot to digits (allowing more flexibility in the input string). Also, leading with the colon is the traditional way to chain commands (it lets you comment out a line at the end of the chain without a syntax error, for one thing).

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley I thought it wouldn't work with the colons on the next line, but you're right, it does!  I tried it in interactive Lua, where it doesn't.

Comment: Remember, the Lua REPL executes a statement as soon as it can, and you can't continue a statement that's already been interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

If your precision is always > 0, then trailing characters are guaranteed to be either sequence of `0` for floats or `.` followed by sequence of `0` for integers. Therefore you can identify and strip this "trailer", leaving rest of the string with:

```
string.format(" %."..precision.."f", value)
   :gsub("%.?0+$", "")
```

It won't mangle integers ending in 0 because those would have float point after significant zeros so they won't get caught as "sequence of `0` right before end of string.

If precision is 0, then you should simply not execute `gsub` at all.

Comment: if the value is 0 the result becomes empty