# How do I fill up a number's decimal places with zeroes?

Tags: lua, decimal-point

Assume the following numbers:

```
local a = 2
local b = 3.1
local c = 1.43
local d = 1.0582
```

My goal is to round these numbers to two decimal places. The result should be this, respectively:

```
a = 2.00
b = 3.10
c = 1.43
d = 1.06 or 1.05
```

Obviously I understand that any number with trailing decimal zeroes will get rounded. `2.00` will be `2`. But I need the numbers as strings, and to make it visually more appealing, I would need these two decimal places.

Here's a function I use to round to two decimal places:

```
function round(num, numDecimalPlaces)
local mult = 10^(numDecimalPlaces or 0)
return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
end
```

This works fine for test cases `c` and `d`, but will produce wrong results with `a` and `b`: it won't fill up with zeroes. I understand it is because the rounding function takes the numbers and calculates them - therefore the excess zeroes get cut off.

But that is exactly not my goal - not cutting them off.

I've tried string manipulation, by checking if and where a `.` is in a number, but that didn't work **at all, for any case**. My method:

```
local zei
if i < 100 then
    if tostring(i):find("%.") == nil then
        zei = round(i, 2) .. ".00" --No decimal point found, append .00
    else
        zei = round(i, 2) --Found decimal point, round to 2
    end
    if tostring(i):find("%.")+2 == tostring(i):len() then
        zei = round(i, 2) .. "0" --Found point, but only one trailing number, append 0
    end
else
    zei = round(i, 0) --Number is over 100, no decimal points needed
end
```

*The above `100` case is just for aesthetics and not relevant here.* Where `zei` is the displayed string, and `i` is one of the test case numbers.

### Summary

How would I round a number to two decimal places, but append trailing zeroes, even if they were excess, e.g. `2.30`? I understand I need strings for this.

[*Contradicting question: **Strip off** excess zeroes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697848/strip-trailing-zeroes-and-decimal-point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't round numbers. You create string representations of those numbers. That would be done by `string.format`, with an appropriate format. Like this:

```
string.format("%.2f", a);
```

Comment: In the lua interpreter used in Fibaro HC2 "%.2f" will format both 3.1 or 3.10 as "3.1".
If it instead is written " %.2f" (space added before %) it give the expected result so apparently not implemented perfectly in at least that case.